# What does it mean when there is a path like /dir/dir/program.attribute?

Tags: files, system, hidden-files

I want to understand how can there be what appears to be "hidden" files that exist. Are they in fact hidden? Or are they attributes of a program? How does one access all the .files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Hidden

A files or directories are "hidden" if they start with a ".".

On the command line you can view them with `ls -A` and from nautilus (your file browser) by showing hidden files <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> or from the menu

[image]

### Path

Your path is where the system looks to find commands.

```
echo $PATH
```

You can set a path , typically in `~/.bashrc`

```
PATH=$PATH:/additional/directory
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept. In Unix, by convention, filenames starting with . are considered hidden - i.e. some programs, such as `ls` or GUI file managers do not display those files. Those files often used to store program settings or other stuff which user normally don't want to see.

This is just a convention and there's nothing magical about those files.

Unlike Windows, Unix does not rely on "file extensions", i.e. a 3-character suffixes after a dot at the end of a filename, to determine the type of the file (i.e. NOTEPAD.EXE etc).

So, in Unix "program.attribute" is just a normal filename, not like a program named "program" has some magical attributes which you can access by specifying "program.attributename"