# File disappeared after cutting name when renaming

Tags: unity, 15.04, filesystem, paths, filename

I use Ububtu 15.04 with Unity interface.

While I was editing a file's name, I accidentally selected the entire name (without the extension) and pressed `ctrl+x` and `Enter`. The file disappeared.

Where did it go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you renamed your file to `.ext` (where `ext` is the original file extension).

Since files whose names begin with a period ("dotfiles") are hidden by default, the nautilus filemanager is no longer displaying it. You can toggle display of hidden files from the nautilus menu <kbd>View -> Show hidden files</kbd> or by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd>.

Comment: And see [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/94780) for more on dotfiles.