# I can't find .local file

Tags: 20.04, hidden-files

I can't find .local in home file

***Inside local file:***

[image]

***Inside home file:***

[image]

Comment: .local is a hidden folder (you know it because its name staerts with a dot). If you want to see hidden files/folder, press CTRL+H in your keyboard.

Comment: Thanks for information

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show hidden files in Nautilus 3.20.3 Ubuntu 16.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837878/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-nautilus-3-20-3-ubuntu-16-10) and also [What are dot-files?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94780/what-are-dot-files).

Answer (score 1):

.local is a hidden directory on my system. In files, you can show hidden files (menu top right - three horizontal lines) has the option to show them. It's inside the home directory.

I hope this helps! :-)